# Laravel eloquent case insensitive data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table in migrations named `currency_codes` with fields `(id, source, code)`.

I also have a model name `CurrencyCode.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CurrencyCode extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'currency_codes';
    protected $fillable = ['source', 'code'];
}
```

Some data from database :

```
+------------------+
|id |source  |code |
--------------------
|1  |USA     |Usd  |
|2  |UAE     |AED  |
|3  |CHINA   |cny  |
|4  |opskins |OP   |
|5  |MyWeb   |wp   |
....................
....................
```

**What I want:** Each and every action `(validation, insert, search)` with this `code` field will be insensitive. I can control from controller with so many lines of code. Can I do this by eloquent model ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, could you elaborate what you want to do?

Comment: I want to query on `code` case insensitive. like: I will write `where('code', '=', $inputCode)` and it will search insensitively. any way to manipulate eloquent model?

Comment: Did you try your query? If you are using mysql it should be case insensitive.

Comment: well it works on mysql. whatif I want to check unique validation on that `code` field?

Comment: Just tested it with the `unique` rule and it works for me, it is case insensitive.

Comment: one last thing, If i run this,  `CurrencyCode::create(['code' => 'anyCase'])`, then it will always store uppercase. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search queries and validation rules are case insensitive when you are using mysql.

e.g.:

```
$query->where('code', $code)
```

```
'code' => 'unique:currency_codes,code'
```

If you want your codes to always be stored in uppercase you can use a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator).

From the docs:

> To define a mutator, define a setFooAttribute method on your model
>   where Foo is the "studly" cased name of the column you wish to access.
>   So, again, let's define a mutator for the first_name attribute. This
>   mutator will be automatically called when we attempt to set the value
>   of the first_name attribute on the model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Set the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['first_name'] = strtolower($value);
    }
}
```

So in your case:

```
/**
 * Set the currency code.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return void
 */
public function setCodeAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['code'] = strtoupper($value);
}
```